# What is the scalar derivative?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I quote paragraph 2.5 of [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) document: *Assume $F(X)$ to be a differentiable function of each of the elements of $X$... $f(\cdot)$ is the **scalar derivative** of $F(\cdot)$*. $X$ is here a matrix.

What is the **scalar derivative**? It is not defined in this document and I have issues to find a definition using Mister Google.

But the way, I'm puzzled by formula (100) of that document:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \mathsf{Tr}(XA) = A^T$$

$X \mapsto {Tr}(XA)$ is a linear form defined on the matrices vector space and therefore it's derivative is itself everywhere

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \mathsf{Tr}(XA).H = \mathsf{Tr}(HA)$$

What is the link with $A^T$?

Comment: [Mister Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scope) provides some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For applied matrix calculus in deep learning the term 'scalar derivative' is used to explicitly confirm that the output of the partial derivative of the function with respect to a variable is a scalar and not a vector.

@mathcounterexamples.net See:

- http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01528.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The simplest explanation is that the word $scalar$ is a typo.

The formula itself seem correct. For instance, let 
$$\eqalign{
 F(x) &= \sin(x) \cr
 f(x) &= \frac{dF}{dx} = \cos(x) \cr
}$$
Then, for a matrix argument $A$, one has the result 
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial\,{\rm Tr}(\sin(A))}{\partial A} &= \cos(A)^T \cr
}$$
...or $\cos(A)$ depending on which layout convention you prefer.